# Where to place Nginx IP blacklist config file?

Tags: nginx, ip, configuration, blacklist

I have an `Nginx` web server hosting two sites.  I created a `blockips.conf` file to blacklist IP addresses that are constantly probing the server and included this file in the `nginx.conf` file.  However in my access logs for the sites I still see these IP addresses showing up.  Do I need to include the black list in each site's conf instead of the global conf for `Nginx`?

Here is my `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # Load virtual host configuration files.
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # BLOCK SPAMMERS IP ADDRESSES
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/blockips.conf;
}
```

blockips.conf

```
deny 58.218.199.250;
```

access.log still shows this IP address.

```
58.218.199.250 - - [27/Sep/2012:06:41:03 -0600] "GET http://59.53.91.9/proxy/judge.php HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" "-"
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you block the ip's further up at your firewall rather than the application

Comment: @sonassi - I definitely could, but the web server should be able to do this as well.  Just curious why it's not.

Comment: Your lines `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/blockips.conf;` would lead to `blockips.conf` to be included twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your log, it IS blocking the traffic, there is a 403 header - ie. Access denied.

Comment: That makes sense, I was under the assumption I wouldnt even see it in the log.  I see other `403` responses for unblocked IP's so I just assumed it was allowing access and failing later.

Comment: Save your bandwidth and CPU time and block them with `iptables` . You should also look into Naxsi if you want to automate the process.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend to place your blacklist in iptables :)
iptables -A INPUT -s 58.218.199.250 -j DROP
That way you dont spend resources processing requests from unwanted ip addresses.

Comment: I upvoted as if you can this is the right approach, however I have nginx behind haproxy so that the source real ip address is that of the haproxy rather than the real ip addreess.